# SQL strategy to fetch maximum

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Suppose I have these three tables:

[image]

I want to get, for all products, it's product_id and the client that bougth it most times (the biggest client of the product).

I solved it like this:

```
SELECT 
product_id AS product, 
(SELECT TOP 1 client_id FROM Bill_Item, Bill 
    WHERE Bill_Item.product_id = p.product_id
    and Bill_Item.bill_id = Bill.bill_id
GROUP BY
    client_id
ORDER BY
    COUNT(*) DESC
) AS client
FROM Product p
```

Do you know a better way?

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2012

Comment: Not sure if it will optimise the query but it's good practise to use `JOIN` so your query could be changed to  `FROM Bill_Item INNER JOIN Bill 
    ON Bill_Item.product_id = p.product_id
    and Bill_Item.bill_id = Bill.bill_id`  You can use `SHOWPLAN` to check the execution plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going to submit pretty much the same thing as @Squirrell only with a Common Table Expression [CTE] rather than a derived table.  So I wont duplicate that but there are some learning points concerning your query.  First is `IMPLICIT JOINS` such as `FROM Bill_Item, Bill` are really easy to have uintended consequences (one of many questions: [Queries that implicit SQL joins can't do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981601/queries-that-implicit-sql-joins-cant-do)) Next for the Calculated column you can actually do this in a `OUTER APPLY` or `CROSS APPLY` which is a very useful technique.

So you could re-write your method as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    Product p
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 b.client_id
             FROM
                Bill_Item bi
                INNER JOIN Bill b
                ON bi.bill_id = b.bill_id
             WHERE
                bi.product_id = p.product_id
             GROUP BY
                b.client_id
             ORDER BY
                COUNT(*) DESC) c
```

And to show you how squirell's answer can still include products that have never been sold all you need to do is join Products and LEFT JOIN to other tables:

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
       p.product_id
       ,b.client_id
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.product_id ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as RowNumber
    FROM
       Product p
       LEFT JOIN Bill_Item bi
       ON p.product_id = bi.product_id
       LEFT JOIN Bill b
       ON bi.bill_id = b.bill_id
    GROUP BY
       p.product_id
       ,b.client_id
)

SELECT *
FROM
    cte
WHERE
    RowNumber = 1
```

Techniques used in some of these that are useful.

- CTE
- APPLY (Outer & Cross)
- Window Functions

Answer (score 2):

the inner query will give you the ranking. The outer query will give you the client that puchase the most for a product

```
SELECT *
(
    SELECT i.product_id, b.client_id, 
           r = row_number() over (partition by i.product_id 
                                      order by count(*) desc)
    FROM   Bill b
           INNER JOIN Bill_Item i ON b.bill_id = i.bill_id
    GROUP BY i.product_id, b.client_id
) d
WHERE r = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Squirrel's answer doesn't return products that have never been sold.  If you want to include those, then your approach is ok, although I would write the query as:

```
SELECT product_id as product, 
       (SELECT TOP 1 b.client_id
        FROM Bill_Item bi JOIN
             Bill b
             ON bi.bill_id = b.bill_id
        WHERE Bill_Item.product_id = p.product_id
        GROUP BY client_id
        ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
       ) as client
FROM Product p;
```

You can also express this using `APPLY`, but a correlated subquery is also fine.

Note the correct use of the explicit `JOIN` syntax.